# What package is this? (symbols)

Tags: symbols, packages, academicons

In [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/recreating-business-insiders-cv-of-marissa-mayer/gtqfpbwncfvp), in the file `mmayer.tex`, line 84--90 we have this line to create small icons:

```
    \email{mmayer@yahoo-inc.com}
%   \phone{000-00-0000}
    \mailaddress{Address, Street, 00000 County}
    \location{Sunnyvale, CA}
    \homepage{marissamayr.tumblr.com}
    \twitter{@marissamayer}
    \linkedin{marissamayer}
```

so `\email`, `\phone`, `\mailaddress` and so on create the small icons I am interested in. Is there are a list of them all?

Comment: The source file has the comment: “AltaCV uses the fontawesome5 and academicon fonts and packages.”

Answer (score 1):

A list of the icons is in the documentation of the `academicons` and `fontawesome5` packages; see their CTAN pages: [academicons](https://ctan.org/pkg/academicons), [fontawesome5](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5).

If, OTOH, you're after a list of fields that `altacv` supports, the best resource I've been able to find quickly is the document class file itself, [on Github](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV/blob/main/altacv.cls), which has

```
\NewInfoField{email}{\faAt}[mailto:]
\NewInfoField{mailaddress}{\faEnvelope}
\NewInfoField{phone}{\faPhone}[tel:]
\NewInfoField{homepage}{\faGlobe}[https://]
\NewInfoField{twitter}{\faTwitter}[https://twitter.com/]
\NewInfoField{linkedin}{\faLinkedin}[https://linkedin.com/in/]
\NewInfoField{github}{\faGithub}[https://github.com/]
\NewInfoField{orcid}{\aiOrcid}[https://orcid.org/]
\NewInfoField{location}{\faMapMarker}
```

suggesting that you can use all those fields (`email`, ..., `location`). It also suggests a way of adding additional fields in case you happen to be on other platforms that are relevant for your CV.

Comment: I don't understand, is there a list of other icons of the same type? I knew about \fanameoftheicon, but they are different. I men something from the same package

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `academicons.pdf` section 2.1 and `fontawesome5.pdf` pp. 3--39 have full lists of the icons those packages contain. What else do you need?

Comment: for example, here is the list of the icons used in that CV,:\email,  \phone
    \mailaddress, \location{Sunnyvale, CA}
    \homepage
    \twitter
    \linkedin. Now, if I add for example another icon, \aiCoursera, it doesn't appear anything